# QT5 cross compile for beaglebone black installation error

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, virtual-machine, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I' attempting to build QT5 for use in a Beaglebone black in a Ubuntu 22.04 Virtualbox VM. I'm attempting to follow the guide here to simplify this process as much as possible:
https://github.com/K3tan/BBB_QT5_guide?tab=readme-ov-file

I'm coming up against a brick wall though and don't know how to get around it. I've used the configuration line

```
./configure -platform linux-g++ -release -device linux-beagleboard-g++ -sysroot /usr/local/linaro/sysroot -prefix ~/Qt5ForBBB -hostprefix ~/Qt5forBBB -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/local/linaro/linaro-gcc/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -nomake tests -nomake examples -no-opengl -opensource -confirm-license -reduce-exports -make libs
```

which seemed to complete without any errors.

When the configuration script completed, it said something along the lines of "run gmake to build". So I did. Unfortunately, I'm running into the following issue:

```
In file included from /home/tim/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtlocation/src/location/declarativemaps/qdeclarativepolylinemapitem.cpp:38:0:

/home/tim/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtlocation/src/location/declarativemaps/qdeclarativepolylinemapitem_p_p.h:381:17: error: ‘const char* MapPolylineShaderLineStrip::vertexShader() const’ marked ‘override’, but does not override

     const char *vertexShader() const override {
```

This is but one of many of the same type of error. All of the errors are const marked 'override'.

I've also got this error

```
home/tim/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtlocation/include/QtLocation/5.15.2/QtLocation/private/../../../../../src/location/declarativemaps/qdeclarativepolygonmapitem_p_p.h: In member function ‘virtual void MapPolygonShader::initialize()’:

/home/tim/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtlocation/include/QtLocation/5.15.2/QtLocation/private/../../../../../src/location/declarativemaps/qdeclarativepolygonmapitem_p_p.h:186:23: error: ‘program’ was not declared in this scope

         m_matrix_id = program()->uniformLocation("qt_Matrix");
```

I would have thought that this would be a straightforward boilerplate process, but that does not appear to be the case. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to resolve these errors?